# Populating Selected Items From Database to MultiSelect Listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access DB and I have created a form in which to select multiple items in a listbox. I have that saving into a database with pipe | delimiters. The issue I am having is when someone needs to go modify the form, I need to populate the listbox with it's normal values, then based on a pull from the database, select the items.

I currently have the start where I split the records pulled from the DB but after that I am lost:

```
temps = Split(records("Pillar"), "|")
```

I know I need to do a *For Each* statement, but am lost. I have tried doing ...

```
For Each varItem In temps
    Pillar.ItemData(0) = varItem
Next
```

But that does not work. That is about as far as I have got as the only other properly value I could use is `Pillar.ItemsSelected` but I receive a read only error when I do that.

Comment: Not entirely. The listbox is already populated based on a Value List in the Access Property Fields. What I need to do now if once the Listbox is populated, highlight the items that are in the database.

Example: The Items are 1, 2, 3 and in the database, the selected values were 1, so when the listbox is shown, it will show 1, 2, 3, but 1 will be highlighted.

I hope I am making sense.

Comment: I have tried doing a `For Each varItem In temps Pillar.ItemData(0) = varItem Next`
But that does not work. That is about as far as I have got as the only other properly value I could use is `Pillar.ItemsSelected` but I receive a _read only_ error when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve `records("Pillar")` which is a string of `|`-separated numbers.  Then `Split()` that string into an array.  The point is to select each list box row whose value matches one of those array members.

However, I don't think you actually need an array.  It should be easier to add a `|` to the start and end of that string, then use `InStr()` to check whether the list box value when enclosed in `|` characters is present in the revised string.

That description was probably difficult to follow.  See whether this example from the Immediate clarifies it.

```vb
cstrPillar = "1|2|3"
? "|" & cstrPillar & "|"
|1|2|3|
strListBoxValue = "3"
? "|" & strListBoxValue & "|"
|3|
? InStr(1, "|" & cstrPillar & "|", "|" & strListBoxValue & "|")
 5
```

If that made sense, here is how I applied it in the click event of my command button.  Note I'm using a string constant, `cstrPillar`, as a proxy for the string you retrieve dynamically with `records("Pillar")`.  And I named my multi-select list box as `lstPillar`.

```
Private Sub cmdSelectRows_Click()
    Const cstrPillar As String = "1|2|3"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To (Me.lstPillar.ListCount - 1)
        Me.lstPillar.Selected(i) = ( _
            InStr(1, _
                "|" & cstrPillar & "|", _
                "|" & Me.lstPillar.ItemData(i) & "|") > 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

The effect of that click event is to select the list box rows matching 1, 2, or 3 and un-select all the other rows.

I realize the `Me.lstPillar.Selected(i)` statement may be challenging.  The best I can suggest is to refer back to the Immediate window example and hope that makes it clear enough.

Comment: Thank you! You are truly a life saver :) (and I don't mean the candy)